# How to make textView highlighted during OnLongClickListener?

Tags: android

I'm sure this is answered somewhere, but I can't find it.

How would I go about making a textview gradually brighten/highlighted during an OnLongClickListener? I have the following code:

```
jObjTv1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(root,"Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Which works just showing me the toast after the long click, but I'd like the textView to be highlighted while being "clicked".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you will have to set a state list drawable as your background for your  TextView

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/background_transition" />

</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll go ahead and do that.